# ELog Sequence Chart: NED filtering eats up messages

Tags: omnet++

For pedagogical purposes, we use the sequence chart view of the eLog file of some simple simulations on our model. It worked pretty well in 4.6, but we finally decided to port the model to the latest OMNET++ 6.0.1. In the new version (we hope the port did not introduce any bug), the sequence chart now does not show the same result.

After running a simulation (the network contains several nodes of the same type) with all the adequate options, we open the sequence chart "editor":

- using the default preset, we see all the events and messages we expect: messages are sent from the transmitting node to the N receiving nodes (5 in the capture below). In this preset however, there are too many things around and we want to filter out unnecessary messages.
  [MSC with default preset and no filtering](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RmMGa.png)
- to do this we add a NED type filter (CSMA), but we then loose too many of these arrows. The messages in question are in fact cloned ones (dup) from the same initial message, sent to different nodes in the network. The message sequence chart contains all the events that we expect, but some messages disappear as if they were not matching the filter. Which seems strange if they are cloned one from the other. Moreover, regardless of the transmitting station, there are always 2 arrows, going almost always to the exact same nodes.
  [MSC with NED type filtering](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AyJ41.png)

As I said before, it worked well in 4.6.

Questions : Are we doing something wrong when filtering on the NED type?
Is there any reason in OMNET++ 6, why some of the cloned/dup messages are filtered out while others are not, given that all the events are still present in the sequence chart?
We would like to provide a simplified version of the model to help on this, but have no clue on the issue... Is there any way to investigate on that?

Any help would be appreciated.